# compress files before upload

Tags: php, upload

hi there i'm trying to compress images before upload them using php, Kindly point me in the right direction...Thanks

```
$target_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/gallery_pic";
      $dosya_sayi=count($_FILES['gallery_pic']['name']);
      for($i=0;$i<$dosya_sayi;$i++){
            if(!empty($_FILES['gallery_pic']['name'][$i])){
          $fileName = $_FILES["gallery_pic"]["name"][$i];
          $target_file = $target_dir .'/'. basename($fileName);
          $endoffile = explode(".", $fileName);
          /* i have changed this part */
          $csstrong = TRUE;
          $gallery_picName = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8,$csstrong)).".".strtolower(end($endoffile));
          $compressedImage = compressImage($gallery_picName, $target_file, 75);
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gallery_pic"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_dir.'/'.$compressedImage);
    
          $_SESSION["gallery_pic"]=$compressedImage;
    
           $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (file_name, ilan_id, category_id)
           VALUES('".$_SESSION["gallery_pic"]."','".$_POST["ilan_id"]."','".$_POST["category_id"]."')";
           if(!mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
                echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
                    die;
            }
            }
        unset($_SESSION['gallery_pic']);
        header("Location: " . "konut.php");
      }
```

Comment: You cannot `compress images before upload` because they exist on the user's computer and you cannot manipulate files on their computer. Once the files have been uploaded then PHP can process/resize/compress them

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius please what are the changes i need to do in th code?

Comment: Do you mean compress files before saving on webserver?

Comment: You have a function in there `compressImage` which is not detailed here. One obvious thing that is wrong is the use of `header` within the loop. If there are multiple files only the first will be processed

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes actually that what i mean

Comment: You should add your `compressImage` function to the question. Use the `edit` link and copy/paste

Comment: Most image files are already compressed. Attempting to compress them further may actually make them larger.